# How to handle a "notify::active" signal from a Gtk.Switch? (MVC architecture)

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3, pygobject

I cannot figure out how to handle the `notify::active` signal of a `Gtk.Switch`. I'm working with the MVC architecture (pattern) [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40498549/mvc-with-python3-and-gtk3).

The error I got is this:

`TypeError: _on_switch_serial_toggled() missing 1 required positional argument: 'state'`

Here's my minimal working example (without a model):

```
import sys
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gio, GObject


class Application(Gtk.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        app_id = "org.iea.etc"
        flags = Gio.ApplicationFlags.FLAGS_NONE

        super(Application, self).__init__(application_id=app_id, flags=flags)

    def do_activate(self):
        # c.Controller(m.Model(), v.View(application=self))
        Controller(None, View(application=self))

    def do_startup(self):
        Gtk.Application.do_startup(self)


class Controller(object):
    def __init__(self, model, view):
        self._model = model
        self._view = view

        self._view.connect('switch_serial_toggled',
                           self._on_switch_serial_toggled)

        self._view.show_all()

    def _on_switch_serial_toggled(self, switch, state):
            if switch.get_active():
                print('Switch ON')
            else:
                print('Switch OFF')


class View(Gtk.ApplicationWindow):
    __gsignals__ = {
        'switch_serial_toggled': (GObject.SIGNAL_RUN_FIRST, None, ())
    }

    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super(View, self).__init__(**kw)

        self._switch_serial = Gtk.Switch()
        self._switch_serial.connect("notify::active",
                                    self.on_switch_serial_toggled)

        self.add(self._switch_serial)

    def on_switch_serial_toggled(self, switch, state):
        self.emit('switch_serial_toggled')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Application()
    exit_status = app.run(sys.argv)
    sys.exit(exit_status)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you are handling the `notify` signal for the `active` property of `Gtk.Switch` **almost** properly. The problem resides in the handling of the custom signal, that you've added to your View.

It's important to understand what you are doing: You have created a View class that has a property, which is a Gtk.Switch. You've also created a signal, called `switch_serial_toggled` associated with this class. Inside the class, you want that, when the internal Gtk.Switch changes state, the View triggers its own "toggled" signal.

This being said, lets fix your code:

**1** - Lets add the toggle state to the View `switch_serial_toggled` as a boolean

```
class View(Gtk.ApplicationWindow):
    __gsignals__ = {
        'switch_serial_toggled': (GObject.SIGNAL_RUN_FIRST, None, (bool,))
    }
```

**2** - Lets give proper names to the arguments of the View internal signal handler and add the state to the emitted signal:

```
def on_switch_serial_toggled(self, obj, pspec):
    self.emit('switch_serial_toggled', self._switch_serial.get_active ())
```

GObject.Object notify signal handler is [described here](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#GObject-2.0/classes/Object.html#GObject.Object.signals.notify)

**3** - Now, let's go to the Controller and handle the View signal correctly:

```
def _on_switch_serial_toggled(self, widget, active):
        if active is True:
            print('Switch ON')
        else:
            print('Switch OFF')
```

`widget`argument is the View instance inside the Controller instance and `state` is the boolean that gets passed with the signal emission.

The full code, with the fixes above, should look like this:

```
import sys
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gio, GObject


class Application(Gtk.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        app_id = "org.iea.etc"
        flags = Gio.ApplicationFlags.FLAGS_NONE

        super(Application, self).__init__(application_id=app_id, flags=flags)

    def do_activate(self):
        # c.Controller(m.Model(), v.View(application=self))
        Controller(None, View(application=self))

    def do_startup(self):
        Gtk.Application.do_startup(self)


class Controller(object):
    def __init__(self, model, view):
        self._model = model
        self._view = view

        self._view.connect('switch_serial_toggled',
                           self._on_switch_serial_toggled)

        self._view.show_all()

    def _on_switch_serial_toggled(self, widget, active):
            if active is True:
                print('Switch ON')
            else:
                print('Switch OFF')


class View(Gtk.ApplicationWindow):
    __gsignals__ = {
        'switch_serial_toggled': (GObject.SIGNAL_RUN_FIRST, None, (bool,))
    }

    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super(View, self).__init__(**kw)

        self._switch_serial = Gtk.Switch()
        self._switch_serial.connect("notify::active", self.on_switch_serial_toggled)

        self.add(self._switch_serial)

    def on_switch_serial_toggled(self, obj, pspec):
        self.emit('switch_serial_toggled', self._switch_serial.get_active ())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Application()
    exit_status = app.run(sys.argv)
    sys.exit(exit_status)
```

Resulting in something like this:

[image]

**PS**: Notice that in step 2, `obj` is the object to which you have connected the signal handler which is similar to `self._switch_serial`. This means that you could use `obj.get_active ()` instead:

```
def on_switch_serial_toggled(self, obj, pspec):
    self.emit('switch_serial_toggled', obj.get_active ())
```